# iAd banner is not showing in iPad mini with iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, iad

I am working with iAd. The ad banner is not showing in iPad mini with iOS 9.2, but it is working fine on all other devices, including iPad.

I checked the iPad setting that the developer ad rate is 100%.

My app is a universal app.

How to solve this issue?

And one another in iPhone 5s iAd banner change color.

```
- (void)createAdBannerView {
    Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (classAdBannerView != nil) {
        self.adBannerView = [[classAdBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.adBannerView.tag = 200;
        [_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([_adBannerView frame], 0,-[self getBannerHeight])];
        [_adBannerView setDelegate:self];
          [_adBannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ];
        [_adBannerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]
          [_contentView addSubview:_adBannerView];    
    }
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    if (!_adBannerViewIsVisible) {
        _adBannerViewIsVisible = YES;
        [self fixupAdView:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation:YES];
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (_adBannerViewIsVisible)
    {
        _adBannerViewIsVisible = NO;
        [self fixupAdView:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation:YES];
    }
}
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Comment: need more information 2 liner cannot explain the problem. Add some code.

Comment: By the way, Apple says: *"The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016."* - [source](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a)

Comment: but test iad banner not work only for ipad mini ios 9.2.work fine all other device.@Pang

Comment: i add code for iad banner.@PoojaM.Bohora

Comment: constraints issues. Why arent you specifying any constraints. Try view debugging.

Comment: Is your app an iPhone app or a universal app? [iPhone apps running on iPad won't display iAd banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2264/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011827-CH1-CREATE_UNIVERSAL_APPS).

Comment: my app is universal app.@Pang

Comment: it's work on all device but only ad not show in ipad mini ios 9.2.check during debugging ipad setting developer ad rate 100% but not show.@uchiha

Comment: Does it work on iPad (not iPad mini)?

Comment: yes it's work but only not work ios 9.2 in ipad mini.@Pang

Comment: *"I checked the iPad setting that the developer ad rate is 100%."* Do you mean the iPad mini setting? Can you clarify?

Comment: thanx to every one issue solve it.@Pang